# 2D Hierarchical clustering library in Java

Tags: java, bioinformatics, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on an Open Source Java project where we need to cluster the heatmap and plot the dendrogram. Are there any 2D Hierarchical clustering libraries available to readily use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [this](https://github.com/lbehnke/hierarchical-clustering-java) library.

You can include the latest version to you pom.xml by adding this ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.apporiented</groupId>
    <artifactId>hierarchical-clustering</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```